# validation of directory or file path allows spaces between folder names but not before and after of / using jQuery Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

Validation of directory or file path allows spaces between words (folder names) but not before and after of `/` using **jQuery Regex**. Please help to achive this.

> **Allowed Path:** C:/Parent Folder/ChildFolder/
>
> **Not Allowed Path:** C:/Parent Folder / ChildFolder/

I have tried using `(/^\S$/.test(path))` but it is not allowing spaces between folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out `^C:\/([\w]+[ ]*[\w]+\/)*$` simple but it checks for at least one word character before and after the `/`

Answer (score 0):

What about: `^C:\/(?! )([^\/]+/(?<! )(?! ))*$`

Broken up, this will always look for a `C:/`, which cannot be followed by a space.

This is followed by any number of directories, which are any amount of characters. These directories must end with a `/`.

The `/` at the end of each directory must not have a space on either side. (Which is done by a look-ahead, and a look-behind: `(?<! )(?! )`)